Azure Action Group could not find logic app workflow
I am trying to create an action group with the Logic App action. While I am able to see my logic app workflow listed in the Select logic app dropdown in the portal, selecting that gives me the error

Failed to get callback URL
Error: The workflow <workflow-name> could not be found.



https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/issues/118  - try out if this helps

Can you refresh the Portal once and try again? @prinkpan

Thank you, @Vijay. It was not a CORS issue for me.


Azure Action Group could not find logic app workflow:

It is a transient issue which may occur due to below factors.
Need to check below:

Check that the logic app workflow state is in enabled mode and also verify that the workflow has existed.

Also verify the actions or URLs provided in the workflow are accessible and are not restricting by any firewalls or network Ip's.

Check that the logic app workflow changes have been saved appropriately and the deployment has successfully completed.

Usually, it is not needed to set CORS origins for triggering logic app action groups. But try adding logic app URL under Allowed Origins to avoid the conflict as shown below.




Make sure that you are creating the action group in the same region as logic app existed as they both have to be in the same region.

After checking all the above, I have tried creating an action group to trigger logic app (standard) workflows (both stateful & stateless) and was able to perform it successfully as shown below.
Output:



If still the issue persists, try retrieving the call back URL using az rest --method using Az CLI as given in this blog.
sub='xxxx'
rg='xxx'
la='standardactionj'
wf='less'
uri="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$la/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/$wf/triggers/When_a_HTTP_request_is_received/listCallbackUrl?api-version=2018-11-01"
workflowDetails=$(az rest --method post --url $uri)
echo $workflowDetails | jq -r '.value'


Note: If still the issue is not resolved, create a new logic app workflow with the same existing configuration and also create a new action group deployment to avoid all these conflicts.
You can also try creating an action group using PowerShell or CLI if portal issue is not resolving.
CLI:az monitot action-group create
PowerShell:New-AzActionGroup

Thank you for the detailed answer, Jahnavi. While debugging this, I realized that my deployed logic app had issues with some parameter syntax. Once I corrected it and made a few other changes, I was able to create the action group using the logic app workflow as an action.
